# Caesar encrypt but wrong output

Tags: c

I check the loop in the paper but still I have no idea why I got the output: "AbabAb" instead of "FcpiXw". Thank you for your help.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void caesar(char a[100], int k)
{
    int d= (11*k)%62; // Displacement interval
    char b[100] = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){ //run a[i] in string a
        for (int j=0;j < strlen(b);j++){ // run b[i] - the alphabet i created
            if(a[i] == b[j])    //if character i in a equal to character b
            {
                if(j+ d < strlen(b)) // if the character moved is still in b
                    a[i] = b[j+ d]; // move a d interval from b[j] to b[j+d]
                else if(j+d >= strlen(b)) // if the character moved is not in b
                    a[i] = b[d + j- strlen(b)]; // start move the char from the start
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char a[100]= "DangVu";
    caesar(a,6);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. What's 62?

Comment: Once you have found `a[i] == b[j]`, you need to *break* the inner loop [here](https://godbolt.org/z/szWczPdxj).